# Symfony 1.4: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Propel::loadData()

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I am in the process of writting functional tests for my website, which uses Symfony 1.4.19 and Propel I am following the documentation for the [Jobeet tutorial (day 9)](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/09?orm=Propel).

I have modified the functional test class as follows:

```
// lib/test/FoobarTestFunctional.class.php
class FoobarTestFunctional extends sfTestFunctional
{
  public function loadData()
  {
    $loader = new sfPropelData();
    $loader->loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/fixtures');

    return $this;
  }
}
```

In my test, I call it thusly:

```
// test/frontend/fooActions.php

<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../bootstrap/functional.php');

$browser = new FoobarTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());
$browser->setTester('propel', 'sfTesterPropel');
$browser->loadData();

// ...
```

From the command line I run the test:

> ./symfony test:functional frontend fooActions

And I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Propel::loadData() in /path/to/site/lib/test/FoobarTestFunctional.class.php on line 7
```

It appears the Propel interface has changed (again?!) between SF 1.2 and SF 1.4, but I can't locate what the new function name is.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: How do you use propel in symfony ? Are you using the default plugin for propel or the one from github (sfPropelORMPlugin) ? Because [loadData still exists](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/lib/addon/sfPropelData.class.php#L62).

Comment: @j0k: I am using the default sfPropelPlugin provided with Symfony 1.4.19

Comment: @j0k: Sorry, It turns out the error was on my part. I have this resolved now.

Comment: By the way, I **REALLY** recommend you to use sfPropelORMPlugin instead of sfPropelPlugin. sfPropelORMPlugin is more up to date.

Comment: @j0k: What are the advantages (this is a new project, so if the ORM plugin is much better), I'd rather use it now (assuming there is not a steep learning curve associated with it?. Also does the loadData() method exist on the new plugin?

Comment: loadData exists (I put a link into my first comment). sfPropelORMPlugin is still maintain, where sfPropelPlugin no more. It also use the last Propel version (1.6), sfPropelPlugin use the 1.4 version. And there is much improvment in 1.6. You will have access to a brand new Query API, much more easier to write query. [Have a look here](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19342/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-j0k)